# Why is my Remote Server not appropriately routing?

Tags: javascript, express

I am having trouble getting my VPS server set up appropriately. I copied all the files recursively from my local server to the remote server, but post & get requests to the server are not functioning appropriately (404 not found error). The routing works perfectly on my localhost server, but unfortunately it doesn't on the remote.

Server Code:

```
// getting datastores
const datastore = require('nedb');
const customerRecordsdb = new datastore("CustomerRecords.db");
customerRecordsdb.loadDatabase();

// importing express
const port        = 3000;
const express     = require('express');
const application = express();
const path        = require('path')
const newPath     = path.join(__dirname + '../../..')

application.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening at " + port));
application.use(express.json( {limit: '1mb'} ));

application.get('/RetrieveCustomerInformation', (request, response) => {
    console.log("SUCCESS!");
    customerRecordsdb.find({}, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            response.end();
            return;
        }
        response.json(data);
    })
})
```

Client Code:

```
// loading data
let numberRecords = 0;
async function loadClientRecords() {
    const response = await fetch('/RetrieveCustomerInformation');
    const data     = await response.json();

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        numberRecords++;
        insertNewRecord(data[i]);
    }
}
loadClientRecords()
    .then(response => {
        // was successful
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //console.log(error);
    })
```

[VPS Page Output]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghoIa.png (The server is not outputting anything)

[Local Host Page output]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6mqE.png
(The server is outputting "SUCCESS!" on every refresh)

As previously mentioned, I simply copied the directory over to the remote server.

Any help to what the problem could be will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a domain for this or are  you just trying to access it from the ip? Also do you have open http channels to receive requests on your server. If so then your express app is set to run on port 3000 so you would have to make an api call to that port assuming your server is allowing access to the ip.

Comment: Right now I am accessing it from the ip address. I'm not sure how to go upon opening http channels to receive requests on the server, I am using Hostinger.

Comment: There are a lot of things that I would need to know to be able to help you here. Since it says you are running a vps then what type of operating system and server are you running? For example ubuntu with nginx or something else? Also how are you accessing your front end? Is it through the ip to your server?

Comment: The operating system is Ubuntu 18.04. I am creating and running the server with node js and express. I am accessing the front end by simply typing in the ip address that was given by Hostinger.

Comment: How are you serving your client side html? Is it through this nodejs app? Is that what your `application.use(express.static(newPath));` is serving or is that something else? Because you obviously have port 80 open and something is serving html files if you can access them.

Comment: I removed the `application.use(express.static(newPath));` for simplicity purposes. I am serving client html with the user visiting the website with an 'index.html' file. I also used ufw to open port 3000 on my remote-server. Still getting no luck.

Comment: If you do something like `sudo ufw allow 3000` you should then be able to access your app on port 3000 like `http://your_server_ip:3000/RetrieveCustomerInformation`. Not recommended but it should work and make sure your app is started. You could try listening to port 80 with your node app but you may have to serve your html with your node app then. I have been trying figure out what you are using to serve your index.html page. Did you just upload html pages to the `var/www/html` folder accessing them directly or are you running a webserver like `nginx` or  `apache` which is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the help, `<URL>:3000/RetrieveCustomerInformation` works as intended. Now seeing "SUCCESS" on the server. For now, I just dropped the files off in the `var/www/html`. I will look into using a webserver. How would I go upon accessing the port when a page is loaded?

Comment: What do you mean by `How would I go upon accessing the port when a page is loaded?`. Let me know. Besides that I would highly suggest using a webserver. I use nginx. Its really easy to set up. Here is a digialocean tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04. It would be the same for any ubuntu server. This way you can easily serve multiple domains and has a lot that will come in handy when you get a domain and an ssl certificate for security. It also allows you to run proxy ports so you don't have to open extra ports for your node apps.

Comment: I got a domain now. I will also setup nginx. When I say how would I go upon accessing the port when a page is loaded, the better question is how can I access the appropriate port?  When I type in `<domain>:3000/RetrieveCustomerInformation` into the browser it works. But when I try to access that port with routes (check client code) I get a 404 error. Thanks for the help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `const response = await fetch('http://your_domain:3000/RetrieveCustomerInformation');` if it works when you type it into your browser then it should work when you fetch it with javascript.